# Building project in visual studio 2015 without internet

Tags: c#, .net, service, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to build my service in debug mode without internet. I have copied all the required dll in a folder and changed the paths of all the references to that folder. But still while rebuilding the project, visual studio tries to download nuget package for those references. Please help.

Comment: If you already referenced dlls from local path, so remove your nuget package dependencies. Did you do that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#uninstall-a-package

Comment: You mean package.config file or package folder containing all dlls from internet? I have deleted only package folder containing dlls downloaded from internet but not package.config file.

Comment: Do not remove nuget packages manual, remove your nuget packages with proper way. Proper way is that I have been mentioned on first comment.

Comment: Yes,uninstalling each nuget package removed packages folder and package.config file as well. This solved my problem. Thanks